# Can someone tell me the purpose of the second capture group in the jQuery rts regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In [Jeff Roberson's jQuery Regular Expressions Review](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/jqueryregex/jQueryRegexes.html) he proposes changing the rts regular expression in [jQuery's ajax.js](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) from `/(\?|&)_=.*?(&|$)/` to `/([?&])_=[^&\r\n]*(&?)/`. In both versions, what is the purpose of the second capture group? The code does a replacement of the current random timestamp with a new random timestamp:

```
var ts = jQuery.now();
// try replacing _= if it is there
var ret = s.url.replace(rts, "$1_=" + ts + "$2");
```

Doesn't it only replace what it matches? I am thinking this does the same:

```
var ret = s.url.replace(/([?&])_=[^&\r\n]*/, "$1_=" + ts);
```

Can someone explain the purpose of the second capture group?

Answer (score 0):

It's to pick up the next delimiter in the query string on the URL, so that it still works properly as a query string. Thus if the url is

```
http://foo.bar/what/ever?blah=blah&_=12345&zebra=banana
```

then the second group picks up the "&" before "zebra".

That's an awesome blog post by the way and everybody should read it.

*edit* — now that I think about it, I'm not sure why it's necessary to bother with replacing that second delimiter. In the "fixed" expression, that greedy `*` will pick up the whole parameter value and stop at the delimiter (or the end of the string) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right.  It was needed in the original because matching the ampersand or end-of-string was how the `.*?` knew when to stop.  In Jeff's version that's no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the article I can't tell you the reason for the second capture group. My intent with the article was to take existing regexes and simply make them more efficient - i.e. they should all match the same text - just do it faster. Unfortunately I did not have time to delve deeply into the code to see exactly how each and every one of them was being used. I assumed that the capture group for this one was there for a reason so I did not mess with it.